# Cant Switch Face Orientation

Tags: mesh

I've created a 3D cup from a simple mesh cylinder and have added the solidify and subdivision modifier. I then applied the solidify modifier to the mesh to select the inside faces and create a liquid from these inside faces. I've applied a material (while also following a tutorial) and it said that by default, when creating this new mesh from the inside faces, the orientation of the normals would be inverted. The tutorial then specifies to select all vertices of the liquid mesh and do shift+n to switch the faces. It works for almost all faces except for one of the face loops that cannot be inverted so their orientation is correct.

I've inserted an image of the mesh

[image]

Comment: Are there any duplicate or "interior" faces (faces between the "inside" and "outside" faces of the glass)? Also, are you supposed to separate (P) the liquid after duplicating the faces to make it? Have you done this?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I have separated the inside faces and it is now its own mesh separate from the glass, so right now its just the 2D faces that make up the liquid mesh. I don't think there overlapping faces at the red part because I have alt+left click deleted it to make sure there is nothing underneath/overlapping

Comment: hello, I don't know what happened but if Recalculate Normals doesn't work and you want to flip these faces, select them and Alt N > Flip, or please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots here is my file https://pasteall.org/blend/c75cacf385be498f92df044e627b0f8c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see if you put your mouse cursor over these faces and press <kbd>L</kbd>, this part is separate, it explains why, when you tried to recalculate the normals, they didn't flip the same way as the rest:

[image]

Now if this part is supposed to be connected to the rest, you can <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* (increase the *Merge Distance* up to 0.01 in the *Operator* box), then recalculate everything with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

If this part is not supposed to be connected to the rest but you want to invert the normals, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Flip*.